# DTLSv1_listen never verifies cookie in ClientHello

Tags: openssl, dtls

I am working on a DTLS server in C#, hoping to use memory `BIO`s exclusively in order to leverage the easy Async sockets in .net.

My problem is that `DTLSv1_listen` doesn't seem to be able to differentiate a `clientHello` *with* a cookie and one *without*. It sends `HelloVerifyRequest`s to all `ClientHello`s regardless.

The veriy cookie callback is also never called. (The generate cookie callback is, of course)

Here is the code:

```cs
    var ssl = new Ssl(_ctx, new MemoryBio(), new MemoryBio());
    ssl.SetOptions(SslOptions.SSL_OP_COOKIE_EXCHANGE);

    rcv = await socket.ReceiveFromAsync(seg, SocketFlags.None, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
    ssl.ReadBio.Write(buf, rcv.ReceivedBytes);

    res = Ssl.DtlsListen(ssl, IntPtr.Zero);

    var bytesWritten = ssl.WriteBio.Read(buf, Ssl.TLS_MAX_RECORD_SIZE);
    await socket.SendToAsync(seg.Slice(0, bytesWritten), SocketFlags.None, rcv.RemoteEndPoint);

    rcv = await socket.ReceiveFromAsync(seg, SocketFlags.None, rcv.RemoteEndPoint);
    ssl.ReadBio.Write(buf, rcv.ReceivedBytes);

    res = Ssl.DtlsListen(ssl, IntPtr.Zero);
    ***Here, rather than calling the cooke verify callback, 
    ***it generates another cookie and prepares another HelloVerify
```

I realize asking an OpenSSL question with C# code examples is a little flaky, but I think you can get the gist off what's going on.

Is there anything that needs to be done to allow `DTLSv1_listen` to work with memory bios? I assumed it would work much like `SSL_accept`, in that you can loop over the function until you get the result you want (or a fatal error...)

Comment: Can you please show the code that configures the _ctx? I have used OpenSSL in C. I supplied both generate_cookie and verify_cookie callbacks with matching logic to work with DTLSListen function.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to register both `generate_cookie` and `verify_cookie` callbacks with matching logic. Secondly, beware of OpenSSL versions 1.1.0 until 1.1.1a that have a [bug](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6934) in DtlsListen. It should only affect if you are using socket bios but worth checking if it also affects memory bios.